# SSMS Syntax Colours

Tags: ssms, datagrip

I'm currently using DataGrip IDE which has it's own SQL syntax colour scheme. I'm used to the syntax colour scheme used in SSMS (e.g. Blue for Keywords; Green for Comments etc.) and I would like to use these in DataGrip - in order to do this I need to know the RGB or Hex colour codes from SSMS, so I can assign them in DataGrip Settings.

So far I've tried:

1. Trawling the 'net but still no luck after going through 50+ results (most of the results are about customising SSMS colour scheme)
2. Checking the [relevant MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/color-coding-in-query-editors?view=sql-server-ver16) which only lists simple colour names, without any codes
3. Getting pictures of SQL text from the 'net and using a colour picker, but the text is too small to get an accurate colour from the pixels

Unfortunately I'm not able to install SSMS just to see if I can pull the colour codes from there as my laptop is administered centrally (work PC) with tight security rules.

Does anyone have an RGB/Hex reference sheet with the SSMS syntax colours? Or can you recommend how to get these?

Comment: *"Unfortunately I'm not able to install SSMS"* Then talk to your adminstrator. Then just get the details of the settings. Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Fonts and Colors -> {Select Text Editor in top Drop Down}  -> {Select Display Item}  -> {Click Custom} -> Consume RGB value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Larnu :-) Unfortunately this is a no-go, as we use BigQuery, so there's little to no justification for installing SSMS. Our IT is primarily handled through our parent company, who are pretty strict on all local PC app installations. Was a bit of a pain just to get DataGrip installed in the first place ;-)

Comment: Then install it somewhere you can and write down all the colour codes you need.

Comment: What if find screenshots in the Internet and then colorpick them?

Comment: Thanks for the response @moscas :-) Ah, I should have mentioned that in more detail in point 3, my bad. It's very difficult to get an accurately coloured pixel due to the small size of the code text.

Comment: Also, you can look through [plugins marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Editor%20Color%20Schemes) and try to find desired one